# BSON ObjectID (Morphia) representation in Typescript/Angular2 Project

Tags: mongodb, angular, typescript, mapping, bson

I have a Java class representing a customer with some properties like name, adress etc.
And I have the property:

```
@Id
@Property("_id")
private ObjectId id;
```

The customer will be fetched from a mongoDB. Everything is fine and all properties are filled. 
Then I try to transport data via REST to a angular2 client
I have a Customer representation in typescript

```
export class Customer {
    public id: string <---
```

Mapping inside rest call in client

```
.map((response: Response) => <Customer> response.json())
```

what do I need to put here, that the property will be mapped and that I can use it within the angular client.
I've tried to install bson-objectid via npm, but I have no idea how to get it to map the id property. All the others are working fine.

Comment: btw. I use moxy to create JSON from classes,
if that information is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found!
Create a

```
public YourAdapterName extends XMLAdapter<String, ObjectID> {
   @Override
   public String marshal(ObjectId v) throws Exception {
       return v.toString();
   }

   @Override
   public ObjectId unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
       return new ObjectId(v);
   }
}
```

This Adapter returns the string representation of the ObjectID and I can use

```
id: string
```

in Typescript.